# How to bind value to dropdownlist in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have several textboxes and one dropdownlist like:

```
       for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
       {
        <tr>
        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GetTimeSheetDetails[i].PROJ_ID, (SelectList)ViewBag.ProjectList, "-- Choose a Project --", new { @id = "ddlProjectvalue" })
        </td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GetTimeSheetDetails[i].SUN_HRS, new { style = "width:50px; height:30px;", @class = "sunhrs" })
        </td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GetTimeSheetDetails[i].MON_HRS, new { style = "width:50px; height:30px;", @class = "monhrs" })
        </td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GetTimeSheetDetails[i].TUE_HRS, new { style = "width:50px; height:30px;", @class = "tuehrs" })
        </td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GetTimeSheetDetails[i].WED_HRS, new { style = "width:50px; height:30px;", @class = "wedhrs" })
        </td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GetTimeSheetDetails[i].THU_HRS, new { style = "width:50px; height:30px;", @class = "thurhrs" })
        </td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GetTimeSheetDetails[i].FRI_HRS, new { style = "width:50px; height:30px;", @class = "frihrs" })
        </td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GetTimeSheetDetails[i].SAT_HRS, new { style = "width:50px; height:30px;", @class = "sathrs" })
        </td>
        </tr>
        </td>
        }
```

and I want to bind data from database to all the fields , every thing is displaying data perfectly, but dropdown list for proj_id is not showing text even though i am passing value to dropdownlist. i am passing like :

```
public int GetTimsheetData(int empid, TimesheetModel TimesheetModel)
{
    // GetimeSheet all the rows according employee name
    var emps = (from n in db.TIMESHEETs
                where n.RES_ID == empid
                select n).ToList();
    int count = emps.Count();
    HttpContext.Current.Session["count"] = count;
    try
    {
        List<TimesheetModel> emptyList = new List<TimesheetModel>();
        TimesheetModel.GetTimeSheetDetails = emptyList; //taking Empty List and bind to GetTimesheetDetails for Add items into it.


        //if Employee Name has more than one record.
        if (emps.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var timeSheet in emps)
            {
                TimesheetModel item = new TimesheetModel();
                item.WEEK_CAL_ID = timeSheet.WEEK_CAL_ID;
                item.PROJ_ID = timeSheet.PROJ_ID;
                item.SUN_HRS = timeSheet.SUN_HRS;
                item.MON_HRS = timeSheet.MON_HRS;
                item.TUE_HRS = timeSheet.TUE_HRS;
                item.WED_HRS = timeSheet.WED_HRS;
                item.THU_HRS = timeSheet.THU_HRS;
                item.FRI_HRS = timeSheet.FRI_HRS;
                item.SAT_HRS = timeSheet.SAT_HRS;
                TimesheetModel.GetTimeSheetDetails.Add(item);

            }

        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    return count;
}
```

and returning to controller like :

```
public ActionResult GetEmployeeDetails(int empId, string btn, TimesheetModel timesheetModel)
{
    Employer_BL employerBL = new Employer_BL();
    ViewBag.ProjectList = timesheetModel.getProjects;

    //If GetTimesheetData returns morethan one record 
    if (employerBL.GetTimsheetData(empId, timesheetModel) >= 0)
    {
        timesheetModel.EMP_ID = empId;

        //passes model data to View 
        return View("Timesheet", timesheetModel);
    }
    TimesheetModel model = new TimesheetModel();
    model.EMP_ID = empId;
    return View("Timesheet", model);
}
```

Where am  I doing wrong, dropdownlist showing  initial index instead of showing text of passing values. Please help me anyone.

in Separate Class I have written like  below to get project names:

```
    public SelectList getProjects()
    {
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> projectslist = (from proj in res.PROJECTs where proj.IS_DELETED == "N" select proj).AsEnumerable().Select(projt => new SelectListItem() { Text = projt.NAME, Value = projt.ID.ToString() });
    return new SelectList(projectslist, "Value", "Text", PROJ_ID);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the `ViewBag.ProjectList` which I cannot found on your source code. You could populate it with an object of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` with one of the item `Selected` properties set to `true`.

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetList()
{
    return (from proj in res.PROJECTs where proj.IS_DELETED == "N" select proj).AsEnumerable().Select(projt => new SelectListItem() { Text = projt.NAME, Value = projt.ID.ToString() }).ToList();
}
```

on your controller

```
ViewBag.ProjectList = GetList();
```

on your view

```
@{
    var projectList = 
        new SelectList(ViewBag.ProjectList, "Value", "Text", Model.GetTimeSheetDetails[i].PROJ_ID.ToString())
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GetTimeSheetDetails[i].PROJ_ID, projectList, "-- Choose a Project --")
```

Comment: I have Edited and Added Code to get project names, please check it.

Comment: You didn't take the result to the `ViewBag` in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this method:

```
[NonAction]
private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetData()
{
    return new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
        new SelectListItem(){ Text="--Select--", Value="0"},
        new SelectListItem(){ Text="A", Value="1"},
        new SelectListItem(){ Text="B", Value="2"},
        new SelectListItem(){ Text="C", Value="3"},
    };
}

Call this function in Action Method
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewData["categories"] = GetData();
    return View();
}


On your html page:
  <%= Html.DropDownList("cat", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["categories"])%>
```

Comment: Thanks for Clue, but i don't want to bind all the data, i want to assign value to dropdownlist to show the text, because i have already bind data,i want to get value when i returning with empid and depends on the value it show text @Shashank

Answer (score 0):

You can use **viewbag** . in your controller you can read your data from the database :

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  ViewBag.ClassName = new SelectList(objclassrep.GetClasslist(), "Id", "ClassName");
}
```

And in your view model you can read the data from controller like this :

```
<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClassId)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ClassId, (SelectList)ViewBag.ClassName);
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClassId)
</div>
```

This code automatically binds ids of your data to DDL **Here is class id**.

This is th getClassList function :

```
 public List<Class> GetClasslist()
        {
            return _dbcontext.Classes.ToList();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for Clue, But my dropdown list contains List like GetTimesheetDetails[index].Proj_Id, i need to pass value to this dropdownlist, i am passing like above, but it is not working.. @Iti Tyagi.

Comment: As you can see in my answer i pass the value to DDL here is class Id.do you type the name of VIEWBAG correctly?

Comment: viewbag works ,but i need to pass value in the form of list, that list values should bind to dropown list , that shows text with respect to value, i have passed values in the form of list, but not working. @ E A