# How to Display the Values from Database to ComboBox in a Windows Form?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, model-view-controller

I have Tried to Display but nothing came up.

```
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("DataSource=10.6.9.58;Initial Catalog=DBNew;User ID=qwertyuiop;Password=1234567890"))
            {
                try
                {
                    string query = "select ID,HRName from HRTable";
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
                    conn.Open();
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds, "HRTable");
                    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "HRName";
                    comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
                    comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables["HRTable"];
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // write exception info to log or anything else
                    MessageBox.Show("Error occured!");
                }
            }
```

The ComboBox shows no Values.
IS there any problem with the database connection or is their anything wrong with the code?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend taking [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask a question.

Comment: Hit a search engine with "C# mvc dropdown data bind",  randomly selected answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22829464/how-to-bind-value-to-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `comboBox1.DataBind();`

```
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "HRName";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
        comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables["HRTable"];                    
        comboBox1.DataBind();
```